# fetch entry in mysql based on conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to query & filter the table objectDetails for user 1,2,3 (We will get rows with id: 1,2,3,4,5). If status is 3 for shared Object then it should discard the row whose status is less than 3 (Here row with id 4 & 5 should be discarded). Here we should get the row with id 1,2,3 as output.

**Here is the table: objectDetails** : Object can be shared by multple user. Status can be between 1 to 3.

```
id, Object , user, status
1 , 00110   , 1      , 1
2 , 00111   , 2      , 2
3 , 00112   , 3      , 3
4 , 00112   , 1      , 1 
5 , 00112   , 2      , 2 
6 , 00113   , 4      , 1 
7 , 00114   , 5      , 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have filtered the data for the user & grouped the object which is shared across user. Then taken out the max status in the grouped data of object for the user.
**Select id, max(status) as status  from objectDetails  where user in (1,2,3) GROUP BY object**;